# How to remove caption for algorithm environment?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I'm using the `algorithmicx` package. I used to get a single line over the top of algorithms when doing

```
\begin{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        ..code..
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

When I changed the above to

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \begin{algorithmic}
        ..code..
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

in order to make the algorithms not float, two horizontal lines now appear over the top of the algorithm. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: you do not need the `algorithm` enviornment at all, just ise `algorithmic`

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394825/controlling-text-above-and-below-caption-in-algorithm/394915?s=2|20.0828#394915 for example.