# Why do algorithm floats' captions not similar to float and table?

Tags: floats, captions, algorithms

In standard and many typical document classes, captions for floats are typeset in a certain mostly uniform way: Centered, smaller font than the surrounding body, slightly spaced above or below the float.

[image]

But - the caption for `algorithm` environments is the algorithm's title, typeset very differently (using `algpseudocode` at least).

[image]

Why is that? Or rather - should I put my `algorithm`s within `float`s?

Comment: The `algorithm` environment (from `algorithm2e`) *is* a float.

Comment: Because it was specified that way by the creator of the package, if you look on https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms you can see that other packages have different ways of doing it.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394825/controlling-text-above-and-below-caption-in-algorithm/394915?s=1|35.2002#394915

Comment: Why? Style decision by the author. Can be customzized. Off-topic for me.